# Cast from 'FIRRemoteConfigValue!' to unrelated type 'String' always fails

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have about 50 of this same warning in my project. Since updating, all of my functions where I call `snapshot.value["something"] as! String` are failing. They all used to work before. I'm not even using the RemoteConfig feature. I just want to retrieve data.

**Example from my User class:**

```
init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        firstName = snapshot.value!["firstName"] as! String
        lastName = snapshot.value!["lastName"] as! String
}
```

**Example from a function (I can give more examples but its basically more of the same):**

```
func loadProfileImage(ref:FIRDatabaseReference) {
        ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
            let base64String = snapshot.value!["profileImgURL"] as! String
            let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
            if let decodedImage = UIImage(data: decodedData!) {
                self.profileImgImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
                self.profileImgImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImgImageView.frame.size.width / 2
                self.profileImgImageView.clipsToBounds = true
                self.profileImgImageView.image = decodedImage as UIImage
            }
        })
    }
```

The app runs because they are just warnings but the warnings are correct because the app fails as soon as it tries to retrieve any data.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue but am trying to actually use the Remote Config as well. Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So apparently having the Firebase/RemoteConfig pod causes this error. As soon as I uninstalled the pod, the warning went away. Definitely putting this in as a bug.

Comment: Have you fixed your problem yet?

Comment: What if you need to use RemoteConfig though?

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same issue, Below code work me perfectely.

Use `valueForKey` Instead of `[]` bracket access value

Then all value goes away...

For Example

**Below code give a warning...**

```
 let someArray = resource["someArrayKey"] as? NSArray
 let someBool = resource["someBoolKey"] as? Bool
```

**Use below code**

```
 let someArray = resource.valueForKey("someArrayKey") as? NSArray
 let someBool = resource.valueForKey("someBoolKey") as? Bool
```

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a bug, but for the time being I think I found a work around.

This was how I pulled information **prior** to importing the RemoteConfig pod

**Old Code**

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath("Data");

_ = databaseRef.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        for (item) in snapshot.children {
            let someValue = item.value!["someKey"] as? String
        }
}
```

And that worked just fine.

After adding `pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'` to my Podfile and running `pod install`, the warning you described above occurred.

This is how I fixed the issue.

**New Code**

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath("Data");

_ = databaseRef.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    if let resources = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            for (key, obj) in resources {
                if let dataObject = obj as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    let someValue = dataObject["someKey"] as? String

                    // Other data types still work
                    let someArray = resource["someArrayKey"] as? NSArray
                    let someBool = resource["someBoolKey"] as? Bool
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Explicity casting the value to a String seemed to do the trick, for me at least.

This is for a database that looks like this:

```
 - Data
     - ObjectOne
          - someKey: 'someStringValue'
     - ObjectTwo
          - someKey: 'anotherStringValue'
```

Answer (score 1):

The value property is a id (AnyObject) and you might need to cast it to dictionary yourself.

```
let val = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary?
firstName = val!["firstName"] as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

This has helped me:

```
if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
```

Comment: Can you elaborate some more on this?

Comment: I just found that here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data
Sometimes their docs are misleading.

Answer (score 0):

this works like charm for me, from the swift file/class in which you are using only Firebase realtime database, remove

`import Firebase`

and add

`import FirebaseAuth`

`import FirebaseDatabase`

make sure to not import firebase database and fire base remote config at same class, this apparently a bug from Google