# Cast from 'FIRRemoteConfigValue!' to unrelated type 'String' always fails when using Firebase Remote Config with Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-remote-config

I am working on an app that uses both FirebaseDatabase and (attempting to use) Firebase Remote Config. I managed to get RemoteConfig to work perfectly, but I am getting the following warning (mind, in a completely different class): `Cast from 'FIRRemoteConfigValue!' to unrelated type 'String' always fails`

This warning is correct because whenever I try to retrieve data from my firebase database as such (for example):

```
let id = snapshot.value!["senderId"] as! String
            let text = snapshot.value!["text"] as! String
            let locationId = snapshot.value!["location"] as! String
```

...my code breaks with no indication of what happened in the console.

What really confuses me is that the Realtime Database and Remote Config work independently of each other, however when both are enabled, the Realtime Database crashes...is this an unfortunate bug in Firebase? Or is it something that I did wrong when writing my code?

Anything helps, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335486/cast-from-firremoteconfigvalue-to-unrelated-type-string-always-fails

Comment: The error message says that the value is of type `FIRRemoteConfigValue` rather than `String`. Read the documentation (⌥-click on the symbol) how to get the string value.

Comment: I have the same issue somewhere else in code where Firebase is not even used! Simply attempting to cast an object to String, Bool or NSNumber, throws this warning. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

The value property in FIRSnapShot is id(AnyObject) requires you to cast to the type by yourself.
Could you try this workaround:

```
let val = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary?
let id = val!["senderId"] as! String
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `valueForKey` Instead of `[]` bracket access value.

> Buggy COde

```
    let id = snapshot.value!["senderId"] as! String
    let text = snapshot.value!["text"] as! String
    let locationId = snapshot.value!["location"] as! String
```

> Solution

```
    let id = snapshot.value.valueForKey("senderId") as! String
    let text = snapshot.value.valueForKey("text") as! String
    let locationId = snapshot.value.valueForKey("location") as! String
```

> `FIRRemoteConfigValue` don't have support to access value using `[]`