# Cast from FIRRemoteConfigValue to unrelated type String always fails : Firebase, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-remote-config

I know this is a **duplicate** of [Cast from FIRRemoteConfigValue to unrelated type String always fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37335486/6297658). But the accepted answer there is that it's just a *bug*.

Which i don't think it is.

According to another solution, I have to force-cast the datatype every time I retrieve or instantiate a variable. I was hoping to find a different and elegant solution to this.

Everything was working fine, but after I installed ***`Pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'`***, I am having this warning on every line I instantiate a variable with a Snapshot value that I receive.

> Cast from FIRRemoteConfigValue to unrelated type String always fails

When I run my app, it crashes there.

**Bugged Code**

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts").observe(.value, with: {(recievedSnap) in

            if recievedSnap.exists(){
                if let dict = recievedSnap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                    for each in dict{

                        let str = each.value["text"] as! String //Line of warning(and crash when the app is run)
                        } 
                }
            }
        })
```

**Working Code**

```
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts").observe(.value, with: {(recievedSnap) in

            if recievedSnap.exists(){
                if let dict = recievedSnap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                    for each in dict{
                        if let eachValue = each.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                        let str = eachValue["text"] as! String
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

I am looking for explanation as to:

- What changed after ***`Pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'`*** installation that it started giving me this error?
- Why am I required to force cast every time I initialize a variable?
- Is there a better approach?

Comment: Forced casting requirement is probably due to new Swift 3 behavior which no longer implicitly casts Objective C objects such as NSDictionary to Swift equivalents. You now need to explicitly cast.

Comment: I had the same issue using swift2, if that were the case then why only after installing `FIRRemoteConfig` pod , it should had been there before as well.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution...

Use `valueForKey` Instead of `[]` bracket access value, because `FIRRemoteConfigValue` dont have support to access value using `[]`

Then all value goes away...

For Example

```
Warning code...
```

Below code give a warning...

```
            let id = snapshot.value!["senderId"] as! String
            let text = snapshot.value!["text"] as! String
            let locationId = snapshot.value!["location"] as! String
```

Use Like this

```
                let id = snapshot.value.valueForKey("senderId") as! String
                let text = snapshot.value.valueForKey("text") as! String
                let locationId = snapshot.value.valueForKey("location") as! String
```

Warming is not appear longer.....

**NOTE: If you use like above then old code also working fine...**

Comment: your answer is not an answer to my question.I was asking the reason behind this warning which you gave to some extent . And secondly `snapshot.value` (Given that you are considering *snapshot* as the retrieved in the completionBlock) does not have a `valueForKey` function. To remove that i will have to cast this to a dictionary type , which brings me to square one. But thanks for the answer